# Wikipedia API: Get results on web browser, not with PHP script

Tags: php, api, wikipedia

I have a PHP script that calls an URL like this :

```
$pageid=$_GET["pageid"] // used for debug
echo json_encode(file_get_contents("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&pageids=".$pageid."&format=json"));
```

When I post a request with parameter 7431, it works like this in the browser : 
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&pageids=7431&prop=extracts

but with the PHP script, it returns Wikipedia help page which tells about the developers at the end.

The page I am getting is entitled "MediaWiki API help" and says "This is an auto-generated MediaWiki API documentation page." before describing LOCALLY the API and saying who the developers and API chifs were and are.

Any idea ?

Comment: You have a typo in your code url :)

Comment: I log the url I am passing to a javascript function using angular, when I click the link, in the inspector it works but through PHP, I am getting the API description page.

I have noticed this is https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spécial:ApiHelp page

Please reload the page.

Comment: the typo was beacause I wrote it manually for the PHP script !

Comment: Sorry ::: got it !

Comment: `action=query` != `query=action`. Please check the URL that you are posting.

Comment: Some web-based APIs return empty results if the user-agent header isn't set.

Comment: @Anthony just added headers that work for me with another query I use with Wikipedia.

Comment: I have Files directive in htaccess

Comment: Done now, thaks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I first had an error in my query as mentionned in the comments. Then, I had another error in my post params in my angular js $http.post in js function.